# How to use the Stores and Orders API on Big Commerce to develop an iOS app?

Tags: ios, bigcommerce

I need to develop an iOS app for a single Big Commerce store that can be used by customers to make purchases . Can the Stores and Orders API be used directly in the iOS app without creating an app on Big Commerce?

Answer (score 0):

The Bigcommerce Orders API does not allow you to process orders. It allows you to create an order processed elsewhere but not to run it through the Bigcommerce checkout process.

Answer (score 0):

The Bigcommerce Stores API does not currently allow you to authenticate as a customer.  You can however, create an order via the API.  In theory, you could process the payment out of band in your app and create the order then via the API.

I've developed a simple Swift API and Cocoapod that I use for accessing the Bigcommerce Stores API via the Legacy API accounts: https://github.com/welbesw/BigcommerceApi